# How to change color of Highlight syntax in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I am using asciidoc extensively for documentation. I am also using the feature **Highlight syntax** feature of asciidoc.

By default it highlight the color in yellow, as in the following link: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/text/highlight/

I googled to find out if it is possible to change the color, but did not find any useful information.

**Question**: Is it possible to change this color. Also is it possible to maintain more that one color for highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

The colour of the highlight is determined by the converter you are using. For example, with the HTML converter, the text is surrounded by `<mark>` tags, and most browsers will style this yellow by default. You can change the colour of the `<mark>` element using CSS.

To add more than one highlight style to your document, you should use a [custom inline style](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/text/custom-inline-styles/). Again, for the HTML converter, style the `<span>` elements using CSS.

Comment: I am making use of chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asciidoctorjs-live-previe/iaalpfgpbocpdfblpnhhgllgbdbchmia?hl=en. I am not sure how to make use of custom inline style. I haven't use asciidoc much except the chrome extension. If you can point me to sample code / documentation of how to put and where to put css and other file structure, I will try it out. For now I just use ascii doc for making note for my future reference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [default stylesheet](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/asciidoctor/asciidoctor@2.0/data/stylesheets/asciidoctor-default.css) for asciidoctor currently contains the following [custom inline styles](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/text/custom-inline-styles/) for highlighting:

```
.aqua-background{background:#00fafa}
.black-background{background:#000}
.blue-background{background:#0000fa}
.fuchsia-background{background:#fa00fa}
.gray-background{background:#7d7d7d}
.green-background{background:#007d00}
.lime-background{background:#00fa00}
.maroon-background{background:#7d0000}
.navy-background{background:#00007d}
.olive-background{background:#7d7d00}
.purple-background{background:#7d007d}
.red-background{background:#fa0000}
.silver-background{background:#bcbcbc}
.teal-background{background:#007d7d}
.white-background{background:#fafafa}
.yellow-background{background:#fafa00}
```

I assume you are converting to HTML, in that case the easiest way to change the highlighting color would be to use these existing inline styles, like this:

```
#Werewolves# are [.red-background]#allergic# to [.aqua-background]#cinnamon#.
```